# Caffe: How to hide network definition?

Tags: c++, caffe

How to hide a network definition, which is in `deploy.prototxt`? Can the network definition be hidden in a `.cpp` file so that it is hidden in the binary executable?

Comment: What's the meaning of the "hide"?

Comment: @Dale 'hide' means that `deploy.prototxt` can be viewed via notepad and I want to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.prototxt` is the Google's protobuf format, which can be stored either in text or in binary format. So, if you just want to prevent viewing it in notepad, you can convert it into binary form.

You can transform a file from text to binary and vice versa by calling Protobuf compiler `protoc` with some flags (`protoc --help` should specify it).

Of course, if you need to secure the definition, you should use encryption.

Comment: For my best knowledge no. But you can encrypt the file, or do it on the fly during serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe solution can be to convert caffe model to format compatible with [TinyDnn](https://github.com/tiny-dnn/tiny-dnn) and just use it for forward pass.